# Does anyone know the UL standard related to resistors and isolation on AC mains?

Tags: ac, voltage-divider, standard, certification, ul

I have a circuit that is attempting to measure AC line voltage 120-240V but I was told by the certification test lab that my voltage divider resistors would require an expensive 3 week soak test. The resistor voltage divider is behind a 275V varistor to clamp the voltage, a fuse to protect from short circuits and the voltage is being sent through a high linearity 3750V isolation optocoupler biased by a transformerless mains side power supply so I was thinking that the circuit would meet the isolation requirements. Unfortunately, this does not seem to be the case.

Now I am trying to understand what I can do to create a DC bias to power the optocoupler and how to reduce the voltage to be able to send through the optocoupler since a resistive voltage divider does not seem valid without extensive testing. As a result, I need more information and the test lab seems unwilling or unable to provide this. A reference to the relevant standard as well as any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: WHo said "soak test"?

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 The OP was "told by the test lab".

Comment: The soak test is being referenced by the certification test lab.

Comment: I meant which Lab?  You can do your own Hipot soak test

Comment: Won't mention the lab to avoid any issues. I am in 3 person shop so not really set up to do that according to standards based on requirements of other required testing. You say it is the Hipot soak test?

Comment: This soak test looks different than what I found for the HIPOT requirements since, they only talk about seconds to minutes: https://electrical-engineering-portal.com/what-is-hipot-testing-dielectric-strength-test

Comment: Jason, the HIPOT Mfg test is to perform either the AC,or normally DC for 60s test or preferred 10% higher for 1 s.  But for a soak test, one can test with any 1uA DC hiV generator ($10) and ramp up slow and leave using 1M series R if the dielectric should fail so current is limited and no damage. Any contaminants may cause flashover with dust and 85% RH but you would not expect on new parts. So I am not sure why this needed.except to verify your resistor ladder has adequate protection. ( e.g. flame proof. Normally datasheets are provided without the need for tests by UL from my experience

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I am at a loss as well. I am looking up high voltage resistors to see if there is any such standard with no luck so far. It is all tied to basic UL-60065 safety.

Comment: There are many classes, standard carbon film 1/4W 350V can withstand 3x this with impulses or as rated.